# How to show new content on button click in JavaFX?

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, applet, javafx-8

Code is at https://bpaste.net/show/b7aa0530f2ac (because of StackOverflow limitations)

I'm currently trying to use

```
//Menu.java

btn.setOnAction(event -> {
    primaryStage.setScene(doubleclick);
    });
```

to change scene from current scene to Scene doubleclick but it isn't found because it is in another class (Mouse.java). Also the variables in that class are needed for it to work. I've tried to copy over the code from Mouse.java to Menu.java but I don't know how to make that work.
[image]

So when I click button in the image above I see what is below: [image]

...instead of the first content (main menu).

Comment: Unclear question. Are you starting with the scene in the first picture, and it is supposed to change to the scene in the second picture? Or is the first picture what you are supposed to see when a button is pressed but the second picture is what you are getting?

Comment: @CameronTauxe
I'm starting with the scene in the first picture, and it is supposed to change to the scene in the second picture.

Comment: and what is happening instead? Is the button doing nothing or is the second stage appearing but looks wrong? Can you post more of your code?

Comment: @CameronTauxe Nothing is happening instead. The button does nothing because I don't know how to make it change scene.

Comment: What's not working with the `primaryStage.setScene(doubleclick);` code you posted?

Comment: @CameronTauxe it can't find the scene because it is in Mouse.java. Because of that I tried to copy the code to the current classs Menu,java but I don;t know how to make use of it there.